# Unattended Upgrade End Script

Tags: apt, scripts, cron, unattended-upgrades

I have the need of notifying my fleet management system every time `unattended-upgrades` run, and sending some information on the packages updated.
Is there any way to detect the end of unattended upgrade and launch a script when the process ends?

So far I have a script that runs daily with this approach:

1. I check for `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` existence.
2. If it exists, parse info from it and report back to the server the update status.
3. Delete the file

Unattended-upgrades run weekly, but the log file is still created daily. Having a hook on unattended-upgrades run would be very handy in my use case, to avoid false reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [systemd path job](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) to listen for changes to the file `/var/lib/apt/periodic/unattended-upgrades-stamp`

That file gets touched when unattended upgrades completes operation. There is no data in the file; the touch merely updates the 'modified' timestamp in the filesystem.

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks, I'll try systemd path job.